# Se puede utilizar dos @rownum en un mismo select?

Tags: mysql

Con este `select` visualizo el *campo* de la *tabla* **persona** con un número correlativo antes del *campo* **nombre**.

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘fila’, nombre
FROM personal t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;
```

La salida es algo así:

> lista / nombre
>  1 Luis
>  2 Carlos
>  3 Esteban

Pero necesito agregar otro correlativo y obtener algo así:

> lista / sublista / nombre
>  1        5       Luis
>  2 6 Carlos
>  3 7 Esteban

Traté de usar algo así:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘fila’, @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘sublista’, nombre
FROM personal t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, (SELECT @rownum:=5) s
```

Pero obtengo esto:

> lista / sublista / nombre
>  5 6 Luis
>  7 8 Carlos
>  9 10 Esteban

Existe alguna manera de lograr lo que necesito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se da porque estas usando la misma varibale `@numrow`.
Deberías crear otra, con un nombre distinto, por ejemplo `@numrow2`.

Así:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘fila’, @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 ‘sublista’, nombre 
FROM personal t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, (SELECT @rownum2:=5) s
```

O usando variables con nombres mas intuitivos:

```
SELECT @fila:=@fila+1 ‘fila’, @sublista:=@sublista+1 ‘sublista’, nombre 
FROM personal t, (SELECT @fila:=0) r, (SELECT @sublista:=5) s
```